# How to get world position of an entity in Amazon Sumerian?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sumerian

In Amazon Sumerian, `ctx.entity.transformComponent.position` gives position of the entity in local space of parent.

How can you get the world position of an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the world position of an entity using the following call:

```
ctx.entity.transformComponent.getWorldTranslation()
```

Additional Info:

1. I did not find any way to directly set the world position of an entity.
2. To set the position use setTranslation().